# How to print to stdout after exec >/dev/null

Tags: shell-script, scripting, echo, stdout, exec

In a script, I have a long list of commands that print to stdout. I want to hide all output. So instead of redirecting each command, I put

```
exec >/dev/null
```

at the beginning.

What options do I have to "temporarily ignore" the general redirection and to have one `echo` call in between actually print to stdout?

Comment: FYI, this has been asked and answered on Stack Overflow; see f/e [How to undo exec >/dev/null in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840322/how-to-undo-exec-dev-null-in-bash)

Answer (score 12):

Any `echo` would print to stdout. It's just that your stdout now points to `/dev/null`. Point being that the original stdout is in no way special, or more "true" than the stdout you have after a redirection.

If you want to keep a copy of where stdout pointed to originally, you can duplicate the file descriptor to another number and send there any output you want to keep:

```
exec 3>&1            # duplicate original stdout to fd 3
exec 1>/dev/null     # send stdout to /dev/null
printf "what\n"      # this goes to stdout = /dev/null
printf "hello " >&3  # this goes to fd 3 = original stdout
# optionally:
exec 1>&3            # put the original stdout back
exec 3>&-            # close fd 3
printf "there\n"     # to current stdout = original stdout again
```

Or in Bash/ksh93/zsh with a dynamically allocated fd (I hope I got this right):

```
exec {orig}>&1            # duplicate original stdout to some fd,
                          # store number in $orig
exec 1>/dev/null          # send stdout to /dev/null
printf "what\n"           # this goes to stdout = /dev/null
printf "hello " >&"$orig" # this goes to fd in $orig = original stdout
# optionally:
exec 1>&"$orig"           # put the original stdout back
exec {orig}>&-            # close fd in $orig
printf "there\n"          # to current stdout = original stdout again
```

In both cases, `ksh93` will mark the fd (3 or `$orig`) with the close-on-exec flag, bash / zsh won't, though with bash 5.2 or newer, you can do `shopt -s varredir_close` for the close-on-exec flag to be added to fds created with the `exec {var}>...` syntax.

When that flag is not set, that means that fd 3 will *leak* to other commands. That could be a problem in practice if the original stdout was going to a pipe for instance and you run a command that starts a background process that could end-up keeping that pipe open. Running `cmd 3>&-` for those can work around the problem.

Comment: Thanks! :) Do I _have to_ put the original stdout back and close 3? Or can I just exit the script and you put it in your answer for completeness?

Comment: @rattlesnake, you're right, I did show it just for completeness, you don't have to put it back if you exit the script. (Note that a _sourced_ script would affect the main shell and its fds too.)

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you. Also: Where is all this 1, 2, 3 coming from? Can I also just call it "originalstdout" instead of 3? `exec originalstdout>&1`

Comment: @rattlesnake, 0, 1 and 2 are the "well-known" fds stdin, stdout, and stderr in that order. 3 is just the first available one after them. (you could use any number up to 9. the ones above that are used by the shells internally.) Mmm, Bash (and other feature-rich shells like ksh and zsh) have a syntax for dynamically choosing an fd number to use on a redirection and storing it in a variable, but somehow the syntax feels awkward. See edit, I hope I got that right.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the `echo` output to go specifically *to the terminal the script was started from*, you could use:

```
echo "some message" > /dev/tty
```

`/dev/tty` is slightly "magic": whichever process uses it, it will always connect to the terminal the process is associated with.

Of course, if you the run the script in such a way that it is *not associated with any terminal* (e.g. from a crontab, or with `ssh somehost script.sh` without specifying the `-t` option to `ssh`), this will cause an error instead.

```
$ ssh hostname "echo foo > /dev/tty"
Enter passphrase for key...:
bash: line 1: /dev/tty: No such device or address

$ ssh -t hostname "echo foo > /dev/tty"
Enter passphrase for key...:
foo
Connection to hostname closed.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a simple list of commands, with one `echo` in the middle,
you can do

```
{
  command1
  command2
  command3
  command4
} > /dev/null
echo 'High five'                       # This goes to the stdout of the script.
{
  command6
  command7
  command8
  command9
} > /dev/null
```

This doesn’t work
if the `echo` is inside a compound command, like an `if`-`then` or a loop.